# Word for when someone says they are good at something they know they are terrible at doing

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I usually find contractors who do this and I am looking for a word to explain it. They are stating a claim, they know they are terrible at doing in order to get your business.

Comment: Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Bullshitter might be harsh but fitting.

Comment: To be polite they are **misrepresenting themselves** or **overstating their abilities** . To be less polite they are **lying**!!!

Answer (score 0):

They are *bluffing*. The usage comes from poker, in which someone who has a poor hand bets as if they have a very strong hand, in hopes of making the other players believe the lie and withdraw.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bluff